# Postgre SQL : Timeout while getting connection from connection pool

Tags: .net, database-connection, connection-pooling, database-administration, enterprisedb

I'm facing problem of connection timeout in postgres SQL.
I across lots of forums but none had helped me till now.

Website works fine for some connections but when a user keep pressing on fatch data button the no of connections gets increased and after some time it starts throwing exception that i have posted in subject.

```
SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity;
```

I have used above query to find open connections but it shows all connections are in ideal mode. I have also attached screen shot for the same.[image]

The problem is i don't want to stop connection pooling as i do not want to meet low performance issue.

Do i need to take care of resources allocated to postgres server?

Website is developed in .NET , Data Adapter is NpgSQL and Postgres Server is Enterprise DB with Postgres 9.0

Let me know if more information is required.
Thank you.